# how to remove debugger warning-tags in Xcode view?

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

Do you know if it's possible to remove all debugger warning-tags in the Xcode view ? I mean those on right, when we compile.

I searched on the Xcode preferences, but couldn't find something about that.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

When you compile, you should not receive any warnings. If you are, then something is wrong with your code. Any warning could result in an application crash, and it is best to solve the problems that cause them rather than ignoring them.

Answer (score 0):

Finally founded !

under View > Message Bubbles > ..